# Ext.Net Inside the dirrect method reach the object customer

Tags: ext.net

I am trying to implement this example ,but I coulnt reach the customer values.for example like this;customer.Name.

```
  [DirectMethod(Namespace = "CompanyX")]
    public void Edit(int id, string field, string oldValue, string newValue, object customer)
    {
        string message = "<b>Property:</b> {0}<br /><b>Field:</b> {1}<br /><b>Old Value:</b> {2}<br /><b>New Value:</b> {3}";

        // Send Message...
        X.Msg.Notify("Edit Record #" + id.ToString(), string.Format(message, id, field, oldValue, newValue)).Show();

        this.GridPanel1.GetStore().GetById(id).Commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deserialize a customer's data.

1. Change "object customer" to "string customer" in the method's signature.
2. Deserialize:

   ```
   Customer c = JSON.Deserialize<Customer>(customer);
   ```